# Rails loop rename

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a loop which contains (0,1,2) as options listed in my database.

In my view I have a checkbox option listing 0,1,2 as selected options, but I wish to rename these in the view. For example 0 = Option 1, 1 = Option 2, 2 = Option 3.

**View**

```
<%= form_for :search, url: search_path do |f| %>
<% @check.each do |c| %>
<%= check_box :check, c.options, {:checked => true}, class: "checkbox inline" %> <%= c.options %>
<% end %>
<%= f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-success' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `check_box_tag`, for example:

```
<ul>
  <% @check.each do |c| %>
      <li>
        <%= check_box_tag "check_options[#{c.id}]", c.id, :name => "check_options[]" -%>
        <%= h c.name -%>
      </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Basically you need to pass the options like an array `check_options[]` and the identification of this option `check.id`. The `check.name` is the checkbox label.

I hope this helps.